# Two round table combinatorics problems.

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling to answer the following two problems:

How many ways can 4 men and 8 women be seated at a round table if there are to be two women and between each man?

How many ways can 15 people be seated at a round table if B refuses to sit next to A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the men be A, B, C, D. In problems about circular permutations, two permutations that differ by a rotation are usually considered to be the same. Equivalently, we can assume that there is a special chair, and that A is sitting on it.

Then the set of *positions* occupied by the men is determined, and the remaining men can be arranged in these in $3!$ ways. For each such way, the women can be arranged in $8!$ ways.

For the second problem, you will find the following approach useful. Call a placement **bad** if A and B are next to each other. Count the number of bad placements, and subtract this from the total number of possible placements.

Another way of solving the problem is to assume as before that A sits in the special chair. How many ways are there to seat B? And now how many ways are there to seat the rest?

**Remark:** It is sometimes a good idea to solve a problem in two different ways. That can provide a (partial) check of correctness.

Comment: What if the conditions of both problem 1 and 2 have to hold at the same time?What if A and B are male and female respectively?

Comment: Ok, I think that if A goes in the fixed seat there are 14! ways to arrange the table around them. Then if B sits on the left or right of A this is a bad position. So there are $2\times13!$ bad positions. This means there are $14! - 2\times13!$ ways for them all to sit together and be happy.

Comment: @rah4927:  That's clearly not the intended interpretation, since $4+8\ne 15$. A problem like the one you refer to *can* be solved, but it would have to be an explicit problem.

Comment: @CaptainMathSparrow: Yes, for the second problem an answer is $14!-2\cdot 13!$.

Comment: @Andre,Well I wasn't paying much attention to numbers.Assume the number of people is 12.So we just use standard complementary counting to solve the problem I am referring to?

Comment: @rah4927: Yes, as you suggest take the "unrestricted" answer of the current first question, and remove the bad ones, of which there are $(3!)(2)(7!)$.